# Intellisense on custom types in Iron Python

Tags: c#, python, intellisense, ironpython

I'm just starting to play around with IronPython and am having a hard time using it with custom types created in C#. I can get IronPython to load in assemblies from C# classes, but I'm struggling without the help of intellisense. If I have a class in C# as defined below, how can I make it so that IronPython will be able to see the methods/properties that are available in it?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public double Weight{ get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public double CalculateBMI()
    {
        return Weight/Math.Pow(Height, 2);
    }
}
```

In Iron python I'd instance a Person object as follows:

```
newPerson = Person()
newPerson.Name = 'John'
newPerson.Age = 25
newPerson.Weight = 75
newPerson.Height = 1.70
newPerson.CalculateBMI()
```

The thing that is annoying me is that I want to be able to say

```
newPerson = Person()
```

And then be able to see all the methods and properties associated with the person object whenever I type:

```
newPerson.
```

Anyone have any ideas if this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it from an editor/IDE, [IronPython Tools for Visual Studio](http://ironpython.net/ironpython/tools/) has that capability (and much more). If you don't have VS 2010 Pro, you can install it into the [Integrated Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e5aa7b6-8436-43f0-b778-00c3bca733d3&displaylang=en).

If you want to do it from the console, I don't believe that it's possible yet.